# r, error in list matching files

Tags: r, text

> Error in listMatchingFiles(i, ignoreMissing = ignoreMissing, lastRound
>   = T) :    File does not exist

I get this error after the following line of codes

```
EUdocvars <- read.csv("EU_metadata.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

EUdocvars$Period <- as.factor(EUdocvars$Period)

EUdocvars$Country <-as.factor(EUdocvars$Country)

EUdocvars$Region <- as.factor(EUdocvars$Region)

EUCorpus <- corpus(textfile(file='PROJECT/*.txt')) 
docvars(EUCorpus) <- EUdocvars
```

Comment: Where's EU_metadata.csv? Also, whatever `.txt` files you're trying to use. You need to provide us the data please. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Why would you expect `'PROJECT/*.txt'` to match a filename? You should also include the `library` calls needed to load all non-base packages.

Comment: setwd("/Users/pc1/Documents/PROJECT")EU metadata is saved in documents